# expressjs not allowing variables to retain scope even when they are not local

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I want to retain values from a mongoDB document to return them as response. The code goes like:

```
exports.UserDiseaseInfo = (req, res, next) => {
    let retval = {};
    let dId = "";
    let subDName = "";
    let body = req.body;
    let UId = (body.UId != undefined) ? body.UId : false;
    let SubDId = (body.SubDId != undefined) ? body.SubDId : false;
    if (UId == false || SubDId == false) {
        res.status(404).send({
            response: "Fail",
            body: req.body
        });
    }

    subDisease_model.findById(SubDId, function(error, doc) {
        dId = doc['DiseaseID'];
        subDName = doc['SubDisease'];

    });

    let data = {
        response: 'success',
        subDisease: subDName,
        DiseaseId: dId

    }
    res.status(200).send(data);
};

However the output is:
{
  "response": "success",
  "subDisease": "",
  "DiseaseId": ""
}
```

Whereas it should be

```
{
  "response": "success",
  "subDisease": "Migraine",
  "DiseaseId": "5ad0850efdcab0ab875c48a4"
}
```

Any advice what am I missing ?

Comment: @Ashish please elaborate

Comment: Please fix the indentation in your code as it is not really readable the way it is.

Comment: Put the definition of `data` and the `res.send()` INSIDE the callback.  That's the only place the database result is available.  The callback is called long after you do `res.send()` so that's why the variables don't have their values yet.  The database call is NON-BLOCKING.  That means the code after it continues to run and the callback is called sometime LATER.  This would be even more obvious if your code was formatted appropriately.

Comment: @jfriend00 would you mind helping with a bit of code

Comment: I don't know what that comment means?  You ask questions here and we try to help.  That's what I did with my previous comment.

Comment: I agree with you @jfriend00 and I really appreciate the help. What I meant was I am still not clear about the non-blocking code, hence asked if you could look at my now formatted code and hint with a bit of mockup code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because query takes some time to return the data that's why you need to put your `data` and `res.send` inside the query callback... That is the only place where `doc` really has data...

```
exports.UserDiseaseInfo = (req, res, next) => {
  let retval = {};
  let dId = "";
  let subDName = "";
  let body = req.body;
  let UId = (body.UId != undefined) ? body.UId : false;
  let SubDId = (body.SubDId != undefined) ? body.SubDId : false;
  if (UId == false || SubDId == false) {
    res.status(404).send({
      response: "Fail",
      body: req.body
    })
  }
  subDisease_model.findById(SubDId, function(error, doc) {
    if (error) {
      let data = {
        response: 'false',
        subDisease: "",
        DiseaseId: ""
      }
      return res.status(404).send(data);
    } else {
      dId = doc['DiseaseID'];
      subDName = doc['SubDisease'];
      let data = {
        response: 'success',
        subDisease: subDName,
        DiseaseId: dId
      }
      return res.status(200).send(data);
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: Also need error handling to do something if there's an error `if (error) {...}`.  Also need to `return` after the earlier `res.status(404).send()`.

Comment: @Ashish thank you the help. However, what if I want to use any values of data outside the callback? I appreciate your time and help.

Comment: @Satya - You can't use them outside the callback unless you pass them to a function that you call from within the callback.  This is how async programming works in node.js.

Comment: @jfriend00, I owe you a bear man. Whenever !! :) Thanks a ton.